# Open new tab onclick table row - plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I use a plugin so when I click on a table row it goes to that url. Now this works fine but I would like it to open as a new tab. I know that " window.open('urlhere','_blank');" opens the url into a new tab but I cant figure out where I should put it. Does anyone know how or has experience with this plugin?

Plugin I use : https://github.com/DeOldSax/clickable-tr-jquery

Plugin code:

```
   (function ( $ ) {

var disableClickClass = 'disable-row-click';
var defaults = {};
var settings;

$.fn.clickableTable = function( options ) {
    settings = $.extend( defaults, options);

    var rows = this.find('tr[data-href], tr[data-event]');

    rows.css("cursor", "pointer");
    rows.find("td." + disableClickClass).css("cursor", "default");

    addClickEvent(rows);

    return this;
};

function addClickEvent(rows) {
    rows.click(function(e) {
        if (notClickable(e)) {
            return;
        }

        var dataEvent = $(this).data("event");
        if ( dataEvent ) {
            if (settings && settings[dataEvent]) {
               settings[dataEvent].call( this, e );
            } else {
                var fun = window[dataEvent];
                if ( typeof fun === "function" ) {
                    fun.call( this, e );
                }
            }
        }

        var dataHref = $(this).data("href");
        if ( dataHref ) {
            var isRemote = $(this).data("remote");

            var id = "uniquy-id-id";
            var aTag = buildATag(id, dataHref, isRemote);
            document.getElementById(id).click();
            aTag.remove();
        }
    });
}

function notClickable(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    return e.target.localName == 'a' ||
        e.target.localName == 'button' ||
        target.hasClass(disableClickClass) ||
        target.closest('td').hasClass(disableClickClass);
}

function buildATag(id, dataHref, isRemote) {
    var a = $('<a></a>');
    a.css('display', 'none');
    a.attr('data-remote', isRemote);
    a.attr('href', dataHref);
    a.attr('id', id);
    a.insertAfter($("body"));
    return a;
}

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: You can add a callback inside the settings: EventName : callback - Try to use e.preventDefault and return false. Also add window.open('urlhere','_blank'); before the return false.

Comment: Why would you ever use some random library to handle your click event? Beyond comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fby0dryg/9/)

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    var $href = $(this).data("href");
    window.open($href,'_blank');
});
```

Exclude the last td Element: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fby0dryg/14/)

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    var $href = $(this).data("href");
    window.open($href,'_blank');
});
$("tr > td:last-child").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Ye I used that before but I couldnt figure out how to exlude the last <td> from the onclick. So I used this plugin which has a disable-row-click class.

Comment: oh give me a sec

Comment: Ye almost works, but in the last td there is an icon that opens up a bootstrap modal which now doesnt open anymore.

Comment: how about this .. now you just select the td: `$("tr > td:not(:last-child)").click(function(){
 var $href = $(this).parent().data("href");
 window.open($href,'_blank');
});`

Comment: Yes it works, thanks. Dont need that plugin anymore.